# Can't download files from S3 using nodeJS: few files don't finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

This is driving me nuts.

I need my server to download 100 relatively small files files from S3 (max 2 Mb).

It always work for ~95% of the files, but it blocks for the last 6-8 files. The `resolve` nor the `reject` callback gets never called...

I tried to download files in parallel ...

- Anyone experienced this?
- Could it be that a packet gets lost and the stream doesn't close?
- Is there a max number of concurrent download?

Here's the code, which technically works in 95% of the cases :

```
  let singleGetFromS3 = (bucket, fileName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let extension = getFileNameExtension(fileName);
      fs.stat(`./${fileName}`, (err, stat) => {
        if (err === null) {
          console.log(`${fileName} exists locally`);
          resolve(fileName);
        } else if(err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          let params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: fileName};
          let file = require('fs').createWriteStream(`./tmp-${fileName}`);
          s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
            .on('error', (error) => { return reject(error); })
            .on('end', () => {
              fs.rename(`./tmp-${fileName}`, `./${fileName}`, reject);
              return resolve(fileName);
            })
            .pipe(file);
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

Using:

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.23.0",
node --version
v4.5.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are listening for the wrong event for when to resolve. You don't want to resolve when all bytes have been read from S3's `Readable`, you want to resolve when `file` is done writing.

```
let singleGetFromS3 = (bucket, fileName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let extension = getFileNameExtension(fileName);
      fs.stat(`./${fileName}`, (err, stat) => {
        if (err === null) {
          console.log(`${fileName} exists locally`);
          resolve(fileName);
        } else if(err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          let params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: fileName};
          let file = require('fs').createWriteStream(`./tmp-${fileName}`);    

          // Listen for the file to be done writing, then resolve
          file.on('finish', () => {
              fs.rename(`./tmp-${fileName}`, `./${fileName}`, reject);
              return resolve(fileName);
            })

          s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
            .on('error', (error) => { return reject(error); })
            .pipe(file);
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this but did not think of a reason for the `writeStream` to close itself. But apparently it works, though I still have 5~6 files that don't complete.... :( :(

Comment: By the way, I'm very astonished to find that such trivial operation in S3 is such a pain in nodeJS...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger If you want to simplify this, I'd start by not utilizing Callbacks, Events/Streams and Promises all in the same function. You should use bluebird.js to `promisify` your `fs` so you dont need the `fs.stat()` callback. Also I edited the answer, don't use the `'close'` event that I originally put, use `'finish'` instead.

Comment: It's not the code that feels complicated, I wrote it, but the fact that I cannot find any working example everywhere around the internet. The `finish` event is triggered after the `close` on, but still, I get a few files that don't finish...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Let me throw something together in a gist

Comment: The worst is that if I `setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, 2000);` the code fails ... o_O ...

Comment: The problem doesn't come from `end`, `close` or `finish` arriving too early, but the event *never* being triggered for some files. And indeed, when I check files, part of it is missing. Why? I have no idea :(

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger https://gist.github.com/pbaio/3ead320ab84f3e14bc4d0323aacf15fa

Comment: I'm confused, but the gist you wrote doesn't work for me... :( I still have a few files for which the download doesn't finish ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137499/discussion-between-peteb-and-augustin-riedinger).

Comment: Sorry I can't dig further, need to sleep. I ended up using https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client which seems to work better. Thanks a lot for support!